# Subscribe to youtube in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, youtube, subscription

I need the functionality of subscription to youtube in my game. I am working on Unity3D. How do I subscribe to youtube and also have a callback for success or failure of subscription.

Comment: Do you mean channel subscription or registering a google account?

Comment: Registering onto the account is my priority.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Google API with OAuth.

While there is no ready API for Unity3d [there is one for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/) that might work. If not, you can always do the HTTP requests by yourself (note: this is quite advanced, use the provided library if possible).

The workflow:

1. First you need to create your application ID with Google (just once).
2. Then you need to [authorize with oauth](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) and request a permission from the user to subscribe.
3. Finally you can subscribe him or her with an API request.

See [Google Developer Console](http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/youtube/v3/youtube.subscriptions.insert) for an live example.

As for knowing if the user has subscribed, you know immediately if the action has succeeded. You can also check his/her list of subscriptions at a later date with a simmilar API call.